# Positional Arguments withDjango url patterns

Tags: python, django, django-urls, url-pattern

I have been stuck on this Django error for a while:

> tutorials() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tutorial_id'

Below are the files. Using Python 3.5 and Django 1.10.

**tutorials/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'tutorials'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<tutorial_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.tutorials, name='tutorials'),
    url(r'^$', views.tutorials, name='tutorials'),
]
```

**tutorials/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Tutorial, Lesson

def tutorials(request, tutorial_id):
    tutorials = get_object_or_404(Tutorial, pk=tutorial_id)
    return render(request, 'tutorials/tutorials.html', { 'tutorials': tutorials})
```

When I visit `website.com/tutorials` I get the error but it will work fine if I go to `website.com/tutorials/1` which is good. But I want to be able to access `/tutorials` so I can ad information to this link.

Comment: get the error is referring to a 404 page?

Comment: What are you expecting /tutorials to do? Your view needs a tutorial ID. If you want to define a URL that doesn't take that ID, you need another view that doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need different functions to serve a collection of tutorials and a single tutorial.

tutorials/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'tutorials'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<tutorial_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.tutorial_view, name='tutorials'),
    url(r'^$', views.tutorials_view, name='tutorials'),
]
```

tutorials/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Tutorial, Lesson

def tutorials_view(request):
    tutorials = Tutorial.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tutorials/tutorials.html', { 'tutorials': tutorials})

def tutorial_view(request, tutorial_id):
    tutorial = get_object_or_404(Tutorial, pk=tutorial_id)
    return render(request, 'tutorials/tutorial.html', { 'tutorial': tutorial})
```

Your need to create a separate template for a single tutorial view.

Comment: Nail on the head!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass this argument via url (1) in your template or make a default value for it in views.py (2).

1. {% url 'tutorials' template.id %}
2. def tutorials(request, tutorial_id=1):

Answer (score 0):

It is because of django url pattern ordering, just change the order since, regular expression `^(?P<tutorial_id>[0-9]+)/` is matched. Options are :

**change the code to**

```
# tutorials_list is different view to handle list
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.tutorials_list, name='tutorials-list'),
    url(r'^(?P<tutorial_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.tutorials, name='tutorials-detail'),
]
```

**or check this in view**,

```
def tutorials(request, *args, **kwargs):
    tutorial_id = kwargs.get('tutorial_id', None)
    tutorials = get_object_or_404(Tutorial, pk=tutorial_id)
    return render(request, 'tutorials/tutorials.html', { 'tutorials': tutorials})
```

with one URL defined int url_patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<tutorial_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.tutorials, name='tutorials-detail'),
]
```

Comment: Good stuff. I just needed to add another view